# Vuetify change location of image depending on the screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify and I am trying to get the image to change the image location for a smaller screen.

My current code: https://codepen.io/yash-dhume/pen/pozMQBg?&editable=true&editors=101

```html
<section>
  <v-container fluid justify-space-between>
    <v-layout column>
      <v-card transition="slide-x-transition">
        <v-layout row justify-space-around align-center>
          <v-flex xs7 align-center justify-center layout text-xs-straight>
            <v-card-title primary-title class="justify-center">
              <div>
                <div class="display-2">About Me</div>
                <p class="text-justify al">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
                  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
                  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
                  sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
              </div>
            </v-card-title>
          </v-flex>
          <div>
            <img max-width="300" src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360"> </img>
          </div>
          <div class="fill-height bottom-gradient"></div>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</section>
```

I would like for the image to be below the about me title then the paragraph after when on medium or a small screen.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the image element in both places that you want it to possibly show.  Then add the `v-if` directive to each and use those with the appropriate vuetify breakpoint object to control what viewports they will load on.

```
<img v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown"  max-width="300" src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360"> </img>
```

Read more about the breakpoint object here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints